# Does a UISplitViewController's master view always have to be a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I've used UISplitViewController several times before without problems (well, problems that I've fixed anyway ;-)  However, I have always previously used a UITableView as the master view, as that's the obvious choice.  Today I have need for something a little different, so I'm just providing a UIView.

However, I'm getting the exception,

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "MyViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

I can't find mention in the Apple documentation that the master view must always be a UITableView in the documentation, there's just a reference to the master view being used to display a list.

Is there a rule that the master view must always be a UITableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

I'd made a mistake by changing the code for the iPad idiom, but testing on an iPhone - whoops!