# SearchBar in SplitViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I added SplitViewController in my app.
As per apple, Masterview must be UITableViewController.

So,I added searcher as Tableview HeaderView.

**Problem**

Searcher is scrolling as tableview scroll.
I want to stick searchBar at top.

**Thank you for your time**

**Help me to solve this**

Comment: You might have added the searchbar on tablview rather than view. Can you add the screenshot of your xib?

Comment: @iphonic
but master view is Tableview as always in Splitview

Comment: You can always change the UITableViewController to UIViewController for the master view.

Comment: @iphonic
I think you can't do that
Because Masterview must be Tableview only

Comment: NO, UITableViewController is inherited from UIViewController, so you can always use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, just that you need create IBOutlet for your UITableView, and may be few modifications in code

Comment: @iphonic, I already tried.
I taken SplitView in my storyboard but not able to change as UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

uisplitviewcontroller masterview will not be always uitableviewcontroller. it can have uiviewcontroller also. check this

[Does a UISplitViewController's master view always have to be a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077075/does-a-uisplitviewcontrollers-master-view-always-have-to-be-a-uitableview)

And additionally you cannot add sticky searchbar in uitableviewcontroller. only possible way is to creating uiviewcontroller and adding searchbar on it.

Here is how this is can be achieved. And it is actually quite simple. (The following example relies on Storyboard, but the mechanism is the same whatever you are using) :

- Use UIViewController and NOT a UITableViewController
- Add  UITableView as the child of the parent UIView
- Add a UISearchBarController also as a child view of the UIView, NOT as a child of the UITableView (UITableView and UISearchController are siblings)

Hope it will help you